# Blender script concatenating names not replacing name

Tags: python

I am trying to use blender script to replace the name of a mesh.
Instead of replacing the name it is concatenating them, for example

```
for meshObject in bpy.data.objects:
    if meshObject.type == 'MESH' and '.00' not in meshObject.name.lower() :   
        meshObject.name = "footprint"
```

I would expect the result to be

`BUILDING001 => footprint`

but it is

`BUILDING001 => footprint_BUILDING001`

When I `print(meshObject.name)` the results are what I expect.

This is kind of blocking me now so any tips would be appreciated.

**EDIT :**

- I am importing obj
- Then I get the mesh
- Rename it
- Export as obj it

When I print the value, it shows as correct. However, once I launch blender and then import the obj again, the result is the same as above.

I think there could be a possibility that I need to do `meshObject.data.name` and `meshObject.name`. but i haven't had to do this in the past.

Comment: The script work fine with me, maybe try another version of blender like 2.80?

Comment: @Hikariztw Thanks for the tip, unfortunately I have to stick with 2.7 for this job, but will update in the future.

Comment: Still cannot duplicate same issue in *Blender 2.79b* and *Blender 2.80.53* with name **BUILDING001** and other similar pattern. Would you mind provide some more information on how this happened to your object names?

Comment: @Hikariztw I have updated the question to give more context.

Comment: More investigating has shown that if i import an `fbx`, and not an `obj` the script works as expected. I will try dig a little deeper to locate the root cause.